# Allow user to remove file owned by root

Tags: linux, files, delete

I have a limited user and access to root. How can I give that user the possibility to remove files owned by root?

I have the following line added in `/etc/sudoers.d/john` : `john ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/opt/OV/tmp/*`yet I'm unable to perform touch or rm commands under /var/opt/OV/tmp. What do I need  extra?

I don't know the syntax or how it should exactly be set, so the user john can execute only rm or touch under /var/opt/OV/tmp/. I'm thinking somewhere allong the lines 
`Cmnd_Alias REMOVE=/bin/rm
 Cmnd_Alias CREATE=/bin/touch
 john ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: REMOVE, CREATE, /var/opt/OV/tmp`. Let me know if this might work or if I need something added/removed. No, the chmod&chown commands will not help since the files under /var/opt/OV/tmp are owned by root.

Comment: That last bit of the line should be a command with optional arguments. Allowing someone to do `rm /var/log/*` using `sudo` would, in my humble opinion, be a _really bad idea_.  It would be better to allow them to run a _script_ (with no arguments) that deleted pre-selected files (or rotated them, even better).

Comment: Could you please give an example? Is `john ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/log/* rm rf` enough ?

Comment: It's an especially bad idea because of the way `sudo` matches wildcards (across word boundaries) - `man sudoers` even warns against this specifically

Comment: surely more like `john ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/rm -rf /var/log/*` ?  This totally wrecks the security of the server.  John would be able to `sudo rm -rf /var/log/../../etc` and trash the server.

Comment: Understood! John's gotta be careful with all that power... I'm guessing if I want john to be able to create and remove files under that directory I would need something like `Cmnd_Allias POWERJOHN= /bin/rm -rf, touch` and `john ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: POWERJOHN, /var/log/*` ?

Comment: Just because i am curious: Why should a normal user delete the files under /var/log? If you have storage limitations, consider the use of 'logrotate'.

Comment: It was just an example. It doesn't have to be specifically /var/log/. Thank you for your suggestion. Does my example from the comments work or should I change anything else? I don't really know the syntax...

Comment: OpenView arrrghhh

Answer (score 2):

You can give an ordinary user permissions to remove files owned by root simply by giving them write access to the parent directory. No need for `sudo`.

In the example, you want the user to be able to delete files from `/var/log`, so you could change the permissions on that directory so your user could create (and therefore delete) files.

You might choose to do this by creating a new group that contained only your user, and changing the group ownership of the directory to match, and then adding group write permission.

```
chgrp johnsgroup /var/log
chmod g+w /var/log
```

Please note that I have not tested this suggestion, and it may be that the group write access is already required by some other application in order to write files to the directory. YMMV as they say.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, however, I would prefer these files to still be owned by root. I just need them removed by `john` under `root`'s ownership.

Comment: @AiureaAdicatotYO who said anything about the files being owned by john? I didn't.

Comment: It's the same as `chown root:john` and the group will be changed. I don't really need any modifications to the folder or files.

Comment: I believe I found what I needed. `setfacl -R -m 'u:john:rwx' /var/opt/` .

Comment: @AiureaAdicatotYO Your comment is very helpful. Please, add also a short answer, so that we can vote for it.

Comment: @meolic that's just a more complicated (and less visible) version of the answer I posted

Comment: ACLs are the bane of sysadmins. They can often be the source of really hard-to-find dysfunctions. Most generic directory-listing and permission-listing tools will not show them To see them, you need specific command-line utilities, which are not always installed by default. Parent-directory permissions answer upvoted.